# Stata read numeric data as string using variable names

Tags: csv, stata

I am reading a csv file into Stata using

```
import delimited "../data_clean/winter20.csv", encoding(UTF-8)
```

The raw data looks like:

```
y             id1
-.7709586   000000000020
-.4195721   000000003969
-.8932499   300000000021
-1.256116   200000007153
-.7858037   000000000000
```

The imported data become:

```
y             id1
-.7709586   20
-.4195721   000000003969
-.8932499   300000000021
-1.256116   200000007153
-.7858037   0
```

However, there are some columns of IDs which are read as numeric. I would like to import them as strings. I want to read the data exactly as how the raw data looks like.

The way I found online is:

```
import delimited "/Users/tianwang/Dropbox/Construction/data_clean/winter20.csv", encoding(UTF-8) stringcols(74 97 116) clear
```

However, the raw data may be updated and column numbers may change. The following

```
import delimited "/Users/tianwang/Dropbox/Construction/data_clean/winter20.csv", encoding(UTF-8) stringcols(id1 id2 id3) clear
```

gives error `id1: invalid numlist in stringcols() option`. Is there a way to specify variable names rather than column numbers?

The reason is leading zeros are missing if I read IDs as numeric. Method`tostring` does not recover the leading zeros. `format id1 %09.0f` only works if variables have equal number of digits.

Comment: Could you please show us how your data look like?

Comment: Yes just updated the question.

Comment: Could you please also indicate us your current Stata version and OS?

Comment: Sorry just see the message. Mine is Stata/MP 16.1 for Mac (64-bit Intel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
import delimited "../data_clean/winter20.csv", stringcols(_all) encoding(UTF-8)  clear
```

PS: Tested in Stata16/Win10

Comment: Thanks! But there are numeric variables that I want to stay as numbers... Would this import those variables as strings as well?

Comment: Exactly, it will import everything as a string. Later you can convert them into numeric using `destring`. For example, in this case:  `destring y , replace`

Comment: Understood. Thank you!!

Comment: @Tian Glad to hear that! Please do consider upvoting the answer in addition to accepting it if you found it helpful.